# Need trigger when user cancel iTunes login while using In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, restore

Recently I have integrated In-App Purchase in my Application and its working great and Restore transaction also seems to be working fine.

Actually I am showing custom Indicator on the window whenever In-App Purchase or Restore Purchases Initiated.

My Problem is how should I dismiss indicator if user clicks to cancel button when App ask for iTunes login.

As of now I am displaying Indicator as soon as user click Restore or buy product and I am able to easily dismiss it in paymentQueue delegate i.e.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

whether payment is Purchased, Failed or Restored

But this delegate will never get called if user Cancel itunes login in-between.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dissmis your custom indicator in

- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error

When you cancel itunes login page this method will be called